# Nice Way to Visualize DCT Coefficients as an Image

Tags: python, image-processing, signal-processing, dct

I took the image below:

[image: lizzards]

Divided it into `8X8` tiles, did a 2D DCT transform on each tile and chopped them to only the first `30` coefficients on each axis. Now I'm trying to visualize the result as an image that will help my intuition on the DCT plane.

Problems:

- The DCT coefficient of `(0,0)` is way larger than all the others
- I want to see a difference between positive and negative coefficients.

So far, the best transform I found is below:

```
def visualize_dct(d):
    d = np.log(abs(d).clip(0.1))
    maxi, mini = d.max(), d.min()
    d = 255*(d - mini)/(maxi-mini)
    return d
```

Which gave me the image below:

[image: dct_visualized]

Full code here:
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ihadanny/my-py-notebooks/blob/master/img_processing_04.ipynb

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it: what I was looking for is histogram equalization. The implementation is quite straight forward:

```
def visualize_dct(d):
    d = d + abs(d.min())
    h = np.histogram(d, bins=1000, range=(0, d.max()))
    c = 255.0*np.cumsum(h[0])/sum(h[0])
    new_img = np.zeros(d.shape)
    for index,value in np.ndenumerate( d ):
        new_img[index] = c[999.0*value/d.max()]    
    return new_img
```

result for a single tile:

[image: tile]
[image: tile_dct]

and for the whole image:

[image: whole_image]
[image: whole_image_dct]

(notice the difference between the simple tiles and the ones with lots of details)

Answer (score 1):

You could shift the values, so that all are positive; then take the individual logarithm (which, by the way, is the basis for conversion to dB), and plot that as colors.

Comment: tried your suggestion and it looks very flat :( did you mean this? d = d + abs(d.min()) + 1.0;
    d = np.log(d);
    maxi, mini = d.max(), d.min();
    d = 255*(d - mini)/(maxi-mini);